# How to synchronize pytorch and openCV image channels?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, pytorch, tensor

In the code that I am writing, pictures are generated and saved with openCV, and I have to read them with pytroch (or convert them to pytorch). The problem I encountered, is that the RGB channels are different using pytorch.read_image, and if I simply convert and permute the original image. See the example here (Very small-scale image to see the tensor values.)

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np
from os import getcwd
from torchvision.io import read_image
import torch as torch

pic = np.zeros((5, 6, 3))
pic[3, 0:7, 0:3] = 255
pic[1:3, 4, 0] = 255
pic[1:3, 2, 1] = 255
pic[4:6, :, 2] = 255

cwd = getcwd()
path = "/".join((cwd, "test/pic.png"))
cv.imwrite(path, pic)

read_im = read_image(path).float()

converted_im = torch.from_numpy(pic).float()
converted_im = converted_im.permute(2, 0, 1)


print("read")
print(read_im)
print()
print("converted")
print(converted_im)
print()
print("difference")
print(read_im - converted_im)
```

With read_image i get the following:

```
tensor([[[  0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.],
         [  0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.],
         [  0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.],
         [255., 255., 255., 255., 255., 255.],
         [255., 255., 255., 255., 255., 255.]],
        [[  0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.],
         [  0.,   0., 255.,   0.,   0.,   0.],
         [  0.,   0., 255.,   0.,   0.,   0.],
         [255., 255., 255., 255., 255., 255.],
         [  0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.]],
        [[  0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.],
         [  0.,   0.,   0.,   0., 255.,   0.],
         [  0.,   0.,   0.,   0., 255.,   0.],
         [255., 255., 255., 255., 255., 255.],
         [  0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.]]])
```

But with converting:

```
tensor([[[  0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.],
         [  0.,   0.,   0.,   0., 255.,   0.],
         [  0.,   0.,   0.,   0., 255.,   0.],
         [255., 255., 255., 255., 255., 255.],
         [  0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.]],
        [[  0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.],
         [  0.,   0., 255.,   0.,   0.,   0.],
         [  0.,   0., 255.,   0.,   0.,   0.],
         [255., 255., 255., 255., 255., 255.],
         [  0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.]],
        [[  0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.],
         [  0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.],
         [  0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.],
         [255., 255., 255., 255., 255., 255.],
         [255., 255., 255., 255., 255., 255.]]])
```

I can simply reconstruct the latter to look like the former, but I am curious if there is an elegant solution for this, or if I am doing something wrong. The images have to be created with openCV and read with pytorch, and the tensors after using the two different methods have to match.

Comment: I believe what's happening is that `cv2.imwrite` writes an image in BGR (instead of RGB) format to disk, which is why when you read it back the channels are in reverse order. I would recommend you use cv2.cvtColor (or manually reverse channels with numpy slice) before saving to disk.

Comment: Hi! Thank you! I didn't know about cv2.cvtColor (I'm fairly new to the subject). I ended up manually changing channels. I was afraid that it takes a lot of time, but and it seems to work quite well.